# Mocking responses in Robospice

Tags: java, android, androidhttpclient, robospice

Is it any possibility to mock responses using Robospice in Android because I need to create demo application which will have all responses in json files in application? I was trying to use https://github.com/andrzejchm/RESTMock but there are some problems, I'm getting information: `RESTMock successfully started!   url: http://localhost:34163/` and nothing else. Any other idea?

Comment: Do you want to mock the responses within  the app its self or have a mock server like RESTMock or Wiremock which your app communicates with?

Comment: It would be great if it could be inside application without any connection to the real servers. So RESTMock is good option but it's not working. I'm starting server in Application class and add `RESTMockServer.whenRequested` but its not working

Comment: are you making your Robospice requests to the url of RESTMock (http://localhost:34163)?

Comment: Yes and my filters look like: `RESTMockServer.whenRequested(pathContains("response"))
        .thenReturnFile(200, "response.json").delay(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 10);`
But nothing happens. Is it working in app normally or only in test classes?

Answer (score 0):

Within your `Application` class you can start RESTMock with:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    RESTMockServerStarter.startSync(new AndroidAssetsFileParser(getContext()),new AndroidLogger());

    RESTMockServer.whenRequested(pathContains("response"))
        .thenReturnFile(200, "response.json");
}
```

This does set up your RESTMock server, but does not do any http requests as of yet. You now need to provide your RESTMock's server url to the methods that fetch data. For example, if you're using Retrofit:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(RESTMockServer.getUrl())
            .build();
```

From now on, each request made using retrofit should communicate with the RESTMock server directly and properly fetch responses that you specify as mocks.